# How to authenticate apps with GCP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We have both android & iOS apps which uses GCP services as their server. As we use Google Cloud functions for our backend services, we authenticate the request via Firebase SDK for NodeJS & use firebase to authenticate the request.
Is there a better way to do auth via GCP, given that firebase & GCP are connected? I looked into GCP Cloud Identity ([here](https://cloud.google.com/identity)) which GCP provides but did not go far with it.

Comment: I think that you should dig more with Cloud Identity -> https://developers.google.com/identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Identity Platform use Firebase Auth Javascript library to authenticated the users, it's more than similar, it's build on top of it!!

You need to have a "gateway" between your user authentication and your function deployed privately and only accessible with identity token (Firebase provide access token). For this, the easiest way is to use Cloud Endpoint. I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). Initially focus on API Keys, but replace the security definition by [Firebase auth security provider](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) and it should work easily!!

Let me know if you have blocking points.

Comment: Worked exactly as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth and Cloud Identity (IAM) are both solutions that are perfectly valid and functional to your app's needs, although Cloud IAM has some advantages over Firebase Auth, specially support for OIDC, SAML and Multi-tenancy, as you can see on this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison) that compares both, you can use that documentation to check what is the best choise for your app, but then again, as mentioned there:

> Identity Platform and Firebase Authentication offer similar functionality.

Since you did not provide any specifics or code on what kind of authentication you are doing, here is a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#end-users) with how to enable Cloud IAM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already imported Firebase auth users to Cloud Identity. Now I don't know how to integrate it with rest of the GCP service. docs on this is also not good. I've bunch of Cloud Function handling HTTP request, as of now, I authenticate via NodeJS SDK.